# I can see wireless networks, but can't connect using Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking

Installed 14.04 on a Gateway E4610D. Changed to a 250mb WD, added 4GB of memory, and a Linksys WMP600N Wireless Card. As far as I know, this card is supported with no other drivers needed. The one change I've made is applied the Macbuntu theme at the link below:

http://www.noobslab.com/2014/04/macbuntu-1404-pack-is-released.html

Now on to my problem. I've done any number of fixes I've found online and everything seemed to make the problem worse, but I was able to reverse everything I did.

I can see all the wireless networks in range, including my two, a 2.4gHz and a 5 gHz. I click connect and the button does nothing. Networking is enabled. I've restarted network manager. I've rebooted the system. I've changed the slot where the wireless card resides. Any ideas?

I forgot to mention. Wired is working. Through some of the fixes it had switched itself to unmanaged, but I got that working again and connect via either ethernet or with my phone.

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you have something to add. It's much easier to have all the relevant information in one place than scattered throughout the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I installed wicd and it worked right away. It would be nice for it to work through network manager though.

Comment: Please add the details of working with `wicd`. You just installed and it started working?